# Thread pool size of ThreadPoolExecutor passed into NioEventLoopGroup in Netty

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

I want to use the `NioEventLoopGroup(int nThreads, Executor executor)` constructor in Netty to create an `EventLoopGroup` for Netty worker and use a `ScheduledExecutorService` to periodically check some conditions and change the thread pool size of a`ThreadPoolExecutor` instance (say `myPool`) passed the 2nd argument to the constructor.

When I tested this, I tried to increase the thread pool size of `myPool` periodically and noticed the following.

`myPool.getPoolSize()` would always be less than or equal to the value of `nThread`.
But the outputs of `myPool.getCorePoolSize()` and `myPool.getMaximumPoolSize()` show that the Core and Max pool size of `myPool` is indeed increasing periodically and it increases beyond the value of`nThread`.

Does `nThread` limit the maximum number of current threads of `myPool`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nThread` is the number of threads that will be used by `NioEventLoopGroup` to process IO. So yes netty will never use more then what you specified there.

Comment: Thanks @Norman. I also looked at decreasing the size of myPool after all nThreads became active and noticed that the current threads (returned by myPool.getPoolSize()) would not decrease even if the client connections are closed and maxPool and CorePool size of myPool decreases beyond nThreads. Is this because the worker threads remain active until shutdownGracefully() is called on the EventLoopGroup?

Comment: Yes... Netty will never return a Thread until the group was shutdown.